# Selecting top level siblings without assigning a class to them

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I am trying to select top level siblings using jquery. I can't use class names which has made the task more difficult.

```
<ul>  
<li>  
    <a href="index.html">1</a>
    <ul>
        <li>  
            <a href="indexsub.html">sub1</a>  
        </li>
        <li>  
            <a href="indexsub2.html">sub2</a>  
        </li>
    </ul>  
</li>  
<li>  
<a href="index2.html">2</a>  
</li>
<li>  
<a href="index3.html">3</a>
</li>
</ul>​
```

Following is the link to JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/KMhzy/28/

I want to change href="#" for all  tags except child list elements (i.e sub1 and sub2).

Comment: your mark-up is not as according to w3c standards.

Comment: You need to think in terms of children and not siblings. Oh and yeah, your HTML works, but is invalid and not doing what you expect.

Comment: I forgot to add a <ul> tags for a sublist item. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to change your HTML (you are missing ul inside nested menu):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="indexsub.html">sub1</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index2.html">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index3.html">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Next, you can achieve what you want with this:

```
$("ul li a").not("ul li li a").attr("href", "#");
```

(other solutions proposed here are hard coded to some 'sub1' value, this should do the trick for all submenus if that is what you want).

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALf5U/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I did not want to use hard coded solution. This example is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

use combination of `.not` and `contains`

```
$("ul li a").not(":contains('sub1')").attr("href","#");
```

**update**

**[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890334/contains-for-multiple-words)**

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/DutpR/1/)**

```
jQuery.expr[':'].containsAny = function(element, index, match) {
var words = match[3].split(/\s+/);
var text = $(element).text();
var results = $.map(words, function(word) {
    return text === word;
});
return $.inArray(true, results) !== -1;
};

$("ul li a").not(":containsAny(sub1 sub2)").attr("href","#");​
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above given code is just a sample. I have more than one child list items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('ul li a[href!="indexsub.html"]').attr("href","#");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** A `ul` can have only list items and inside a list item adding another list item without defining a `ul` or `ol` tags is considered as a wrong syntax.

Correct markup as according to W3C Standards:

```
<ul>  
    <li>  
        <a href="index.html">1</a>
        <ul> 
            <li>  
                <a href="indexsub.html">sub1</a>  
            </li>  
       </ul>  
   </li>
   <li>  
       <a href="index2.html">2</a>  
   </li>
   <li>  
       <a href="index3.html">3</a>
   </li>
 </ul>​
```

And the code suggessted by **Pragnesh Chauhan** is working as expected.

```
$("ul li a").not(":contains('sub1')").attr("href","#");
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jYJLM/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above given code is just a sample. I have more than one child list items. i.e sub1, sub2, sub3 in reality.

Comment: It's only wrong syntax because the second `</li>` closing tag becomes disassociated from its original opening tag, which becomes an error. If you remove it, then you get two `li`s in the same `ul`, which is correct HTML but incorrect XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want:

```
$("ul li:first-child a").attr("href","#");
```

​
And the jsFiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/KMhzy/43/

PS: It will work for multiple childs too... :)

Comment: @Umair Cheema: Here, it's `:first-child` selector which does the trick. It'll only select the first level children of the search pattern. :)