# Find element whose immediate descendant contains text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have:

```
<div id="new">
  "hello new"
    <div id="some">
      "hello some new man"
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the div whose immediate descendant has text "hello some". i tried:

```
$('div:contains("hello some")')
```

this shows both div's with id's new and some

I have some many div's with different ids, but contains the text "hello some". I want to select all such div's

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7896669/1719752

Comment: i hope there should be something simpler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890334/contains-for-multiple-words

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XPath` for this purposes, and it's `text()` function.

```js
function getElementByXpath (path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
// get any element containing this text
getElementByXpath('//*[contains(text(), "hello some")]')
```

```html
hello some
```